# Is DMA effective for small packets?

Tags: operating-system, embedded, stm32, dma

Is DMA chip effective for small data packet like 5 bytes.

I am working on a embedded project with STM32, I am using DMA for receiving 3 bytes packet but when using DMA to transmit 5 bytes packet, I don't get the packet at the receiving side immediately, but when using a normal transfer, I get the packet more quickly.

So can we say that DMA is not effective for small packet ?

Comment: Receiving on what interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with using DMA for receiving is that the DMA transfer interrupt occurs then the DMA buffer if full and/or half-full, if receipt of the packet does not fill the buffer to reach the half or full-transfer threshold you will not get an interrupt to indicate the availability of the data.

So say your receiver has 6 byte DMA buffer and generates an interrupt at the half and full transfer, you send a 3 byte packet and you will get an interrupt at the end of every packet.  If you send a 5 byte packet, you will get an interrupt for the first three bytes, then the next two bytes will sit in the buffer indefinitely until one more byte (from the next packet) arrives.

So it is not really a matter of "small packets" but rather packet alignment with the DMA buffer.  It is not even in fact a matter of "packets" - if the data were a stream, you end up with the same problem when the data stream ceases if it happens not to be a multiple of the DMA buffer size.

Moreover even if the packets are an exact multiple of the DMA buffer size, if you get data loss over the link, you will no longer be aligned with the buffer and will encounter the same problem.

The solution in this case if to set a timer on each receive DMA half/full transfer to use as a timeout.  The timeout would normally be set to something a little more than the time taken to transfer one half of the buffer (assuming you are using the half/full transfer to allow double or "ping-pong" buffering), so that if the buffer half/full transfer is not achieved, the timer expires and on the timer handler you retrieve the data that *has* been transferred.  When the DMA half/full transfer interrupt *does* occur, you need to account for the data you have already retrieved in the timer interrupt, and just retrieve the new data.

So you would implement a driver where data is retrieved from the buffer on any of a DMA half-transfer, full-transfer or timer interrupt, and in the timer handler you maintain a count or index to the last buffer position retrieved so that in a half or full transfer you only retrieve the new data.

If your buffer is long and your packets small, and the data is not streaming, you could get several timer interrupts between DMA interrupts. In that case you might make your timeout smaller than the DMA buffer fill time.  The optimal solution may depend on the nature of the data being transferred and the latency you can sustain.

If you can sustain the interrupt rate of one interrupt per character, then it will always be simpler to avoid DMA for receiving data, but it will never be "ineffective", just more complicated to get right.  Your problem here is not that small DMA transfers are ineffective, but rather that your implementation is sub-optimal.